# How to find out the state of a checkbox using AndroidViewClient

Tags: android, python, automated-tests, androidviewclient

I'm using androidviewclient for automated black-box level  testing of an android GUI, I have two checkboxes (YES and NO) with YES checked by default, I use vc.touch() to select NO and I need to know whether NO has been selected.The way I do it now is by taking screenshot before and after a touch and compare them. Is there any easier way to find the state of the button/check-box. It seems touch() is a void function outputting nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an example, I'm using **Clock** and the **Vibrate** checkbox in Alarms

[image]

Then, I generated the script using [culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/wiki/Culebra-GUI) and manually added the `assert` at the end (it could be done in one line but I added 2 for clarity)

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
'''
Copyright (C) 2013-2016  Diego Torres Milano
Created on 2016-06-03 by Culebra v11.5.6
                      __    __    __    __
                     /  \  /  \  /  \  /  \ 
____________________/  __\/  __\/  __\/  __\_____________________________
___________________/  /__/  /__/  /__/  /________________________________
                   | / \   / \   / \   / \   \___
                   |/   \_/   \_/   \_/   \    o \ 
                                           \_____/--<
@author: Diego Torres Milano
@author: Jennifer E. Swofford (ascii art snake)
'''


import re
import sys
import os


import unittest

from com.dtmilano.android.viewclient import ViewClient, CulebraTestCase

TAG = 'CULEBRA'


class CulebraTests(CulebraTestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.kwargs1 = {'ignoreversioncheck': False, 'verbose': False, 'ignoresecuredevice': False}
        cls.kwargs2 = {'forceviewserveruse': False, 'useuiautomatorhelper': False, 'ignoreuiautomatorkilled': True, 'autodump': False, 'startviewserver': True, 'compresseddump': True}
        cls.options = {'start-activity': None, 'concertina': False, 'device-art': None, 'use-jar': False, 'multi-device': False, 'unit-test-class': True, 'save-screenshot': None, 'use-dictionary': False, 'glare': False, 'dictionary-keys-from': 'id', 'scale': 0.5, 'find-views-with-content-description': True, 'window': -1, 'orientation-locked': None, 'save-view-screenshots': None, 'find-views-by-id': True, 'log-actions': False, 'use-regexps': False, 'null-back-end': False, 'auto-regexps': None, 'do-not-verify-screen-dump': True, 'verbose-comments': False, 'gui': True, 'find-views-with-text': True, 'prepend-to-sys-path': False, 'install-apk': None, 'drop-shadow': False, 'output': '/home/diego/tmp/culebra/checbox.py', 'unit-test-method': None, 'interactive': False}
        cls.sleep = 5

    def setUp(self):
        super(CulebraTests, self).setUp()

    def tearDown(self):
        super(CulebraTests, self).tearDown()

    def preconditions(self):
        if not super(CulebraTests, self).preconditions():
            return False
        return True

    def testSomething(self):
        if not self.preconditions():
            self.fail('Preconditions failed')

        _s = CulebraTests.sleep
        _v = CulebraTests.verbose

        self.vc.dump(window=-1)
        checkbox = self.vc.findViewWithTextOrRaise(u'Vibrate')
        self.assertTrue(checkbox.isChecked())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    CulebraTests.main()
```